# Issue with Excel in IIS

Tags: asp.net, excel, iis, powerpoint

I create excel file with chart and it's working on my local machine with VS inbuilt iis. But when I deployed it on hosting server it's not working. My environment is :
-Win2K8
-IIS 7.0
-MS Office profession
-PIA (2010 tried)

Very first time, I was getting error :

*Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE))*

After some configuration like Dconfig allowing access for Networking service and created desktop folder with full write permission to everyone but I din't got succeeded. Even now I am not getting any error but file is not opening (Excel and PPT). I check our custom application log and system log.

Please guide me why this happening?

Comment: MS doesn't support office automation on server http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Comment: Yes you are right, it has some work around to do that. Like give Launch permission for DCom ms excel component and create a new folder under config/sysprofile and give write permission for everyone. It's working for some of the person. Bu in my case either not getting any error message or not displaying.

Comment: you are looking for trouble :) and think about if that site receives some traffic, it will fall in spectacular way

Comment: Thanks Antonio for suggestion. The only issue is I am thinking about the rework for my all efforts devoted to create multiple charts like Bar, Column, Line etc. i have to rework again on it.

Comment: well, I can sympathize with you, but I think that there is no other way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Office Open XML to create your files instead of automation. There are several libraries out there that will help you build Excel files. I personally use [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) and think it's pretty decent.

Comment: I used interop to create Chart with Excel and PPT so is it possible to create using EPPlus?

Comment: Hi Charlie, Can we show the dataLabel on series? I tried using the Epplus but I didn't saw any property OR method to do that.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the answer to that question. I would open a new question on StackOverflow to ask that.